# Is Microsoft forms doesn't allow to upload photo with organizational account?

Tags: forms, service

I want to make Microsoft form with file upload option. Does organizational account allow files upload with any anonymous user? If yes how? Or no why?

I have concern with super administrator. He is not aware with this service.